# mysql select a value within a select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an implementation messages system.
My problem is, I would like to know whether a user already has a thread with another user and if so what is the mid

I have a messages_recips table which look like this

```
---------------------------     
| mid | seq | uid | status|
|--------------------------
| 4   | 1   | 1   | A     |
| 4   | 1   | 2   | A     |
---------------------------
```

if user id 1 having a thread with user id 2  I hold 2 rows with same mid.
I know I can create 2 sqls to achieve what I'm asking for, but I'm trying to do it in 1 sql.

Comment: Have you tried joining the table with itself?

Comment: I think you have to write a self join query.

Select u.uid from tablename u
INNERJOIN tablename u1 on u.mid = u1.mid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to write a self-join query:

```
Select u.uid, u1.uid from tablename u
 INNER JOIN tablename u1 on u.mid = u1.mid
```

You will get all the users who have the same mid.

In order to get only user1 and user2 records you have to place a where clause at the end of the query lik this.

```
 Select u.uid, u1.uid from tablename u
 INNER JOIN tablename u1 on u.mid = u1.mid
 Where ( u.uid In ( 1,2 ) OR u1.uid In ( 1,2 ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but that would return all messages between users,I would like to receive user_id1 and user_id2 and check whether there is a thread between them

Comment: Well here is what I have done , not sure it the best way but...Select u.mid from tablename u
 INNER JOIN tablename u1 on u.mid = u1.mid and u1.uid = '1' where u.seq = 1 and u.uid='2' LIMIT 1 , let me know what you think

Comment: for that you have to place a where clause at the end of the query lik this.`Where ( u.uid In { 1,2 } || u1.uid In { 1.2 } ;`see my updated ans.

Comment: there is no need to place LIMIT in your query and also no need to include u.seq = 1

Comment: Don't use `&&` and `||`. There is an `AND` and an `OR` operator in SQL.

Comment: Trying to run the select but still getting errors even after adding the missing ")" and changing the "." to ","

Comment: please again see the answer I have removed all the errors from the query.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Waqar Janjua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/826659/waqar-janjua), the key to this is a self-join query:

```
SELECT m1.mid
  FROM messages_recips AS m1
  JOIN messages_recips AS m2 ON m1.mid = m2.mid
 WHERE m1.uid = 1
   AND m2.uid = 2
```

Comment: Slight change to who ever will read this answer after the AND replace m1.uid to m2.uid